# Issue with Exchange EWS web application

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have a web application that I made to connect to my Exchange EWS that mainly looks at a user's Outlook categories. Not sure what changed recently but when connecting, the webpage outputs the following error - Error: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Where can I begin troubleshooting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my httpRuntime targetFramework to

The server no longer accepts anything but tls 1.2 and the target framework as set to 4.5 which doesn't support tls by default.